# can I have dynamic string for suggestedInvocationPhrase in Siri shortcuts?

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I want to know can Siri suggestion can have suggestedInvocationPhrase dynamically ?

> As I say "order soup" I can show custom UI for that because I have
>   already defined it in suggestedInvocationPhrase - **DONE**
>
> But when I say "Order soup with pizza" OR "Order soup with p
>   asta".
>
> Here **pasta** and **pizza** can be dynamic. - **Want to achieve**

Is it possible with siri kit ? I have used custom intent ?

I have taken reference from

https://medium.com/swift2go/creating-custom-siri-shortcuts-25d1284e0720

https://github.com/artrmz/siri-shortcuts-demo

Please help me if you know the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked ?https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/3003422-deferredlocalizedintentsstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question  as I have completed this task and the conclusion is

**`"You can not have suggestedInvocationPhrase dynamically" for SiriKit`**